# Gradlew | Build not happening | Java project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have been at it for 3 hours now and still haven't been able to get it to work.

I am using gradlew command for clean build (./gradlew clean build) but it fails saying

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
  Please read the following process output to find out more:

---

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
  Please read the following process output to find out more:

---

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  ```
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:160)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:136)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.doStartDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:212)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:130)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:93)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:207)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:402)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:375)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:23)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:368)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:298)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
  ```
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I am using corretto-jdk 1.8. Configured Gradle JVM to use the same. Configured the same JDK in the project.
My project runs fine. Able to run Junit test cases as well. But when doing ./gradlew clean build it gives me the above error

Comment: I solved it!! I guess i was using both sdkman & jenv, both of which were using different versions of jdk. JAVA_HOME was using jenv to use the jdk that it was using. And when running gradle it was using the jdk version defined by sdkman. As a result it wasn't working properly. I just set the jenv java to point to the same jdk version being used by sdkman.